# Failed to restore plugin "NetworkStatus" from config.xml. You might need to try adding it again. Error: Error: npm: Command failed with exit code 1

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, npm

I'm trying to build an Android APK in Ionic but I'm getting the following error:

```
Discovered saved plugin "NetworkStatus". Adding it to the project
Failed to restore plugin "NetworkStatus" from config.xml. You might need to try adding it again. Error: Error: npm: Command failed with exit code 1
Error output:
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 'NetworkStatus' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 name can no longer contain capital letters
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  'NetworkStatus@latest' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 Your package name is not valid, because 
npm ERR! 404  1. name can no longer contain capital letters
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\IONIC\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-10-11T20_47_57_623Z-debug.log`
```

I'm using the following command to build the release APK:

```
ionic cordova build android --prod --release
```

also my config.xml look like:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><widget id="io.ionic.starter" version="0.0.1" 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" 
xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
<name>App</name>
<description>Descreption</description>
<author email="info@demo.com" href="http://demo.com/">App</author>
<content src="index.html" />
<access origin="*" />
<access launch-external="yes" origin="whatsapp//*" />
<allow-intent href="whatsapp:*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
<preference name="ScrollEnabled" value="false" />
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19" />
<preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
<preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
<preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
<preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
<platform name="android">
    <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application" 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" />
    </edit-config>
    <resource-file src="resources/android/xml/network_security_config.xml" target="app/src/main/res/xml/network_security_config.xml" />
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
    <splash density="land-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
</platform>
<platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    <icon height="57" src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" />
    <icon height="114" src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
    <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" />
    <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
    <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
    <icon height="20" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-20.png" width="20" />
    <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-20@2x.png" width="40" />
    <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-20@3x.png" width="60" />
    <icon height="48" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-24@2x.png" width="48" />
    <icon height="55" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-27.5@2x.png" width="55" />
    <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-29.png" width="29" />
    <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-29@2x.png" width="58" />
    <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-29@3x.png" width="87" />
    <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" />
    <icon height="80" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
    <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@3x.png" width="120" />
    <icon height="88" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-44@2x.png" width="88" />
    <icon height="50" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" />
    <icon height="100" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
    <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" />
    <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
    <icon height="180" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
    <icon height="72" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" />
    <icon height="144" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
    <icon height="76" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" />
    <icon height="152" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
    <icon height="167" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" />
    <icon height="172" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-86@2x.png" width="172" />
    <icon height="196" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-98@2x.png" width="196" />
    <icon height="1024" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-1024.png" width="1024" />
    <splash height="480" src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
    <splash height="960" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
    <splash height="1024" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
    <splash height="768" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" />
    <splash height="1125" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-2436h.png" width="2436" />
    <splash height="1242" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
    <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
    <splash height="1536" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />
    <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@~ipadpro.png" width="2048" />
    <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@~ipadpro.png" width="2732" />
    <splash height="1136" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
    <splash height="1334" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
    <splash height="2208" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
    <splash height="2436" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-2436h.png" width="1125" />
    <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~universal~anyany.png" width="2732" />
</platform>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.3.3" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="2.4.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="2.0.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="5.0.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" spec="^4.0.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard" spec="^2.0.5" />
<plugin name="NetworkStatus" value="org.apache.cordova.NetworkManager" />
```

I'm using rest api in this project to get data from database & post data to database. but it gives the error at the time of build apk or run apk.

Comment: Can you post your config.xml?

Comment: You will need to update you plugins to latest version, since as I assume you must have added ios as platform more recently and plugins would have been added 1.5 years ago.

So those plugins must have already been fetched into plugins directory 1.5 years ago and must be of lower version to whats recently available.

Comment: Did your error got solved??

Comment: **Yes...Thank You...**

Answer (score 1):

You are using the very old Cordova syntax (From 2.9.0) for Android as stated [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.9.0/cordova/connection/connection.html).

First, remove the latest line in the config.xml:

```
<plugin name="NetworkStatus" value="org.apache.cordova.NetworkManager" />
```

Then, make sure you have the updated Cordova using `cordova -v`. If it needs an update, update your global Cordova to the latest `npm update -g cordova`, then update the platforms and plugins.

For more info, you can check [How to update Cordova?](https://ionic.zone/cordova/update)

After updating Cordova, install the network information `cordova-plugin-network-information` plugin. You can check the documentation in the [Ionic Docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/network) for more details and how to use it.